# php `strtotime` variable not returning a negative number?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Looking to form a variable in the form of the number of days between two dates.

```
$dayDiff = round((strtotime('2012-02-18') - strtotime('2012-02-22')) / 86400);
```

The above displays "-4" which is correct!

```
$newDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dayDiff . " day"));
```

The above treats `$dayDiff` as a positive number and spits out '2012-02-25' instead of the wanted result of '2012-02-14'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will output :

```
$dayDiff = round((strtotime('2012-02-18') - strtotime('2012-02-22')) / 86400);
echo $newDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dayDiff . " day", strtotime('2012-02-18')));
```

or:

```
$firstDate = strtotime('2012-02-18');
$dayDiff = round(($firstDate - strtotime('2012-02-22')) / 86400);
echo $newDate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dayDiff . " day", $firstDate));
```

the `strtotime` will work from the current timestamp and not from the 18th, this is why if you output: `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));` it will output today's date, `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now - 4 days'));` the 25, and `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2012-02-18 - 4 days'));` the 18th -4 days will output 14.

more info on strtotime: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: This did it and I did not fully understand the `strtotime`, thanks for explanation

Comment: @ToddN Please see the link I attached, it explain pretty much everything you need to know about strtotime. But basically, strtotime start at the epoc time (1970 Jan 1 @ 00:00:00) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time. Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

You should find this helpful:

http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-adding-and-subtracting-dates/